# Sp_who2 function SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to know what is the query that is being executed at that moment

```sql
CREATE TABLE #sp_who2 
(
    SPID INT,Status VARCHAR(255),
    Login VARCHAR(255),
    HostName VARCHAR(255), 
    BlkBy VARCHAR(255),
    DBName VARCHAR(255), 
    Command VARCHAR(255),
    CPUTime INT, 
    DiskIO INT,
    LastBatch VARCHAR(255), 
    ProgramName VARCHAR(255),
    SPID2 INT, 
    REQUESTID INT
) 

INSERT INTO #sp_who2 
    EXEC sp_who2

SELECT * 
FROM #sp_who2

-- Añadimos los filtros aqui :
--WHERE       DBName like ' WideWorldImporters'
-- Añadimos el order  by aqui :
ORDER BY DBName ASC
--Importante borrar la table temporal :
DROP TABLE #sp_who2
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download and use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/). By default, it will show the text of the currently executing queries. It also has additional features and options to facilitate capturing activity for forensic analysis.